# Can we change "#comments" from URL in the Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, url, comments

In my Wordpress site, all the contents of URL in my language, Turkish. When I want to link to a page's comments, I have to write it like this: `http://siteadi.com/icerigin-basligi/#comments`. I don't mind normally, but I don't want URL, a part of it to be in Turkish and some in English. So I want to change `#comments` with `#yorumlar` in the theme.

I know, we can do this with changing `get_comments_link()` function in the `wp-includes/comment-template.php`. But I think, this is not a good solution, because if the theme is updated, the edited content will also be deleted. So I want to do this with the theme page. Is it possible or do I have to do it in `wp-includes/comment-template.php`?

[image]

Comment: Never hack the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Do never edit core files*** 
(located in /wp-includes, /wp-admin etc.) . Do not do it! (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/what-are-some-reasons-why-you-should-not-hack-wordpress-core-files).

If you are using a ready-bake theme then you have to create a child theme (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), copy the comments.php file from your main theme into it and change `id="comments"` to `id="yorumlar"`.

```
<div id="yorumlar" class="comments-area">
```

This way you can still update your theme without destroying any changes.

If you have developed a theme yourself just change the name of the ID in comments.php to your needs.

Note: *In a multilanguage page HTML IDs are usually not translated as this causes problems with CSS, JavaScript and anything else. An HTML ID / anchor is a technical thing which should be language independent while usually english is used as global internet default language (last but not least because of the ASCII charset).*